# How to vertical align a text and an tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I am using a TikZ picture followed by a text. How do I create a picture that aligns with the top of the text?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)] {
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,-3);
} text
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to shift the baseline lower to shift the `tikzpicture` higher, e.g. by the height of a `\strut` or something between 1ex (height of lowercase letter) and 1.6ex (~height of uppercase letter), depending on your liking.
<sub>See also my question [Determine height and depth of letters relative to the font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22225/determine-height-and-depth-of-letters-relative-to-the-font-size) for a discussion about the correct height.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\tikz[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)}] {
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,-3);
} text
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

`yshift={-\ht\strutbox}`:

[image: Result]

`yshift={-1.2ex}`:

[image: Result]

Comment: By trial and error, I found `yshift={-1.1*\ht\strutbox}` was about the right amount to center a circle vertically with the text. Anyone know a more exact way to accomplish this?