# How to make a tikz node, top-aligned with the rest of the text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

If I write

```
before-text \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm} line1\\line2\\line3\\ \end{minipage} after-text
```

I get a box, whose top is aligned to the top of "before text". I would like to have the same, when using a `tikz` node (with `line1\\line2\\line3\\`) instead of `minipage`. But the default behaviour is to align the bottom of the node with the bottom of the "before text".
How can I do this?

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Does this post help: [How to vertical align a text and an tikzpicture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23652/5764)

Comment: You can find the relevant discussion in the manual page 117 about `baseline` key.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To align the contents of the `tikzpicture` you have some possibilities.

TikZ calculate the bounding box of every picture. If you don't set the bounding box manual the whole picture will be used. TikZ define a node which can be use to reference the calculated bounding box. The node name is `current bounding box`. 
However important is the key `baseline` which is the reference for the vertical alignment of the `tikzpicture`. This key can be set at the beginning of the environment.

An example with `current boundingbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Text before
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)},outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw (2,0)--(3,0);
\node[align=left,] at(1.5,0) {\strut line1\\line2\\line3\\line4};
\end{tikzpicture}
Text between
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south),outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw (2,0)--(3,0);
\node[align=left] at (1.5,0) {\strut line1\\line2\\line3\\line4};
\end{tikzpicture}
Text after
\end{document}
```

An example where the node was named and the node can be used for the vertical alignment. The example was provided by [percusse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQGp9.png)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

before text 
\tikz[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]a.north)},outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] \node[align=center] (a) {\strut line1\\line2\\line3\\line4};
text between
\tikz[baseline=(a.south),outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] \node[align=center] (a) {\strut line1\\line2\\line3\\line4};
text after
\end{document}
```

Every `node` / `tikzpicture` have a space around. The spaces are `inner sep` and `outer sep`. To align the text you have to set this seps to 0pt. (or calculate the new resulting height). The command `\strut` for the alignment of the `north` is required to set a fix height at the first line of the node. In this way you can shift the baseline by a fix height.

[image]

Comment: @Werner: Now ;-)????

Comment: yes, the baseline option + the yshift={-\ht\strutbox} parameter do the job very well. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yay for vertical alignment + up-vote-ability. :)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel : could you explain what does actually the `\strut` before `line1` ?

Comment: @nicolasroy: Do you know the command `\strut`

Comment: no ... i have to admit :(

Comment: @nicolasroy: `strut` is a font specific box. The height and the depth will be increased if you increase the font size. The width is always zero. The height of `\strut` is equal to `0.7\baselineskip`.

Comment: The first part of the above answer with `yshift={-\ht\strutbox}...` is in my judgement the smartest-- as I'll have to change nothing inside the `tikzpicture` content... but only add a _complex enough_ option for me to figure out in another twenty years !  Maybe this answer owes a "plus-plus-plus-five" from me !

Answer (score 11):

If you add `text width=<width>` to the node option the content is wrapped in a top align `minipage` internally. Together with the `baseline` option you can achieve the requested alignment. The drawback is that you need to set the width of the node. I tried replacing the internal `minipage` with a `varwidth` environment, but without success.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

before
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(A.base)}]
    \node [text width=2cm] (A) at (0,0) {first\\second\\third};
\end{tikzpicture}
after

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It's the good method.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

before text 
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\height+\baselineskip-1pt}{% 1pt is \interlineskip
  \tikz \node (a) {\tabular{c} line1\\line2\\line3\\line4\endtabular};}
text between
\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\baselineskip-1pt}{%
  \tikz \node (b) {\tabular{c} line1\\line2\\line3\\line4\endtabular};}
text after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the interested party, in order to remove the extra `tabular` padding, using a column alignment of `@{}c@{}`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm taking another bite at the same question. With a vastly improved solution, I think --- thus the new answer.

I looked at `tikz` code: the vertical alignments are hard wired to the bottom line, except the fixed width environment in LaTeX (and only LaTeX). I'm going to prepare a patch for this, soon, until then, an easy hack.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  base/.is choice,
  base/top/.code={\let\vbox\vtop},
  base/bottom/.code={\def\pgfutil@minipage[t]{\minipage[b]}},
  % base/bottom/.code={}, % for plain TeX
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text before \rule{1cm}{0.4pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={align=center,anchor=base},baseline=0pt]
  \node at (0,0)[text width=2cm,base=bottom]
        {automatic line breaks with base at the bottom};
  \node at (2,0)[text width=2cm,base=top]
        {automatic line breaks with base at the top};
  \node at (4,0)[text width=2cm,base=bottom]
        {manual\\line breaks\\with\\base at the\\bottom};
  \node at (6,0)[text width=2cm,base=top]
        {manual\\line breaks\\with\\base at the\\top};
\end{tikzpicture}
\rule{1cm}{0.4pt} text after
\end{document}
```

Extremely simple to use: say `base=top` or `base=bottom`. If you don't specify anything, you get the (crazy) default behaviour.

As far as I can see, redefining `\vbox` (uuuu, scary!:) and `\minipage` has no ill effects. Looking at the code, all the redefinitions stay in a very local group. 
---Ahh well, as you can see from the updated image, there *is* a side effect... But the alignment works ;-)

[image: top/bottom-base aligned multiline text of fixed/variable width]

Comment: This is not needed. Martin's answer is just enough to do this without redefining `\vbox`. You just need to give a name to the node and if you like for the bottom placement the regular `before \tikz[baseline={([yshift={0.5\ht\strutbox}]A.south)}] \node [text width=3em] (A) at (0,0) {first\\second\\third}; after` is enough. Also naming the style as `base` can conflict with the existing `base` default anchor name.

Comment: I was looking for a more general (and also easy-to-use) solution. General also in the sense that it would work for all shapes! ---About the name, I don't really care, but I think it makes sense to call it `base` because that's what it does, it determines where the base is. Is anchor base used as a key name at any point?

Answer (score 5):

I was bugged by the same problem for quite a while... and I think I have finally found a solution that's usable in everyday life ;-)

I defined a new (generic) anchor `top base`, which does the job in non-complicated cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{top base}{%
  \csname pgf@anchor@#1@north\endcsname
  \pgf@anchor@generic@top@base@main
}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{top base west}{%
  \csname pgf@anchor@#1@north west\endcsname
  \pgf@anchor@generic@top@base@main
}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{top base east}{%
  \csname pgf@anchor@#1@north east\endcsname
  \pgf@anchor@generic@top@base@main
}
\def\pgf@anchor@generic@top@base@main{%
  {%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@ya
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@ya
    \pgf@ya=0pt
    \pgfutil@loop
    \ifdim\pgf@y>\baselineskip
      \advance\pgf@y-\baselineskip
      \advance\pgf@ya\baselineskip
    \pgfutil@repeat
    \global\pgf@y=\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

The following node
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [align=center,baseline=(a.base)]
  \node(a){sticks\\up};
\end{tikzpicture}
while the next one
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [align=center,baseline=(a.top base)]
  \node(a){sticks\\down};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of first example]

The anchor (actually, the three anchors, because I also defined the east and the west version) is then of course usable also in within a `tikzpicture`. An example follows.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,every node/.style={draw,outer sep=2pt}]
  \node(a){first node\\with\\some text};
  \node[anchor=top base west,at=(a.top base east)] (b)
       {this node\\is anchored\\at top base\\and positioned\\at top
         base\\of the node\\on its left};
  \node[anchor=base west,at=(b.top base east)](c)
        {this node\\is anchored\\at base\\and positioned\\at top
         base\\of the node\\on the left};
  \node[anchor=top base west,at=(c.base east)](d)
        {anchored\\at base\\positioned\\at top
         base\\of the left node};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result of second example]

How does it work? It first deduces the height (without depth) of the original box where the node text was typeset. Then it estimates the number of newlines by counting how many `\baselineskip`s fit in the height, and sets the `top base` anchor that much to the north.

The problems: two. First, the procedure fails if a font larger than `\baselineskip` was used in the box --- ok, I can live with that.  Second, much more problematically, it only works for some shapes (rectangle, ellipse, and some others). For other shapes it is impossible to deduce the height of the original box; the information is of course there when saved anchors are computed, but then it gets lost... more precisely, it cannot be recovered from saved anchors and dimensions. I'm thinking the only way to hack this is to define a new shape (say `circle'`), inheriting everything from `circle` and adding additional saved dimensions/anchors.

I hope this helps, although it is not as generic as the name suggests :-)

Comment: You are allowed to insert a link to image location. Users with enough reputation are then able to change it into an image link (simply by adding the exclamation mark).

Comment: Today I had the time to take a look on your code. Luckily meanwhile you had provided links to the images, so I could insert them. (BTW: upvoted, of course!)

Comment: :-) I don't know why I didn't think of links myself... Thanks for the advice!