# Make Answer Box Inline with Text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the article document class. How do you make an answer box that is in line with the text like in the picture?

[image]

Comment: From the attached image, one can think the you want the boxes only on the right of `enumerate` environment  items.  Is this so?

Comment: That's right. Then, the box is located in the middle of the first line and the last line of the text.

Comment: What will be the purpose of that box?  You need to have some kind of access to it, I suppose.

Comment: The box is a place to write answers to questions on the side. The desired answer is only a short answer (the final result is like a number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is using a table, I am using `tabularray` here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,counter,varwidth}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{BAGIAN PERTAMA}
    
    \vspace{3mm}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[.5cm,c]X[j]Q[c,3cm]},rows={m},cell{1-5}{1}={r=1,c=1}{h}}
        \mycnta. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-
        tis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent
        imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo,
        lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
        nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Prae-
        sent in sapien. & \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] \draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,1.5); \\
                  &             &                                         \\
        \mycnta. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-
        tis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent
        imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo,
        lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
        nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Prae-
        sent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. & \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] \draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,1.5); \\
                  &             &                                         \\
        \mycnta. & \blindtext & \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] \draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,1.5); \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been thinking about the idea of using a table for a while and haven't figured out how to position the box right in the middle of the beginning and end of a sentence. Thanks and this has solved my problem above.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I use `TikZ` to create a node for the item's text and to draw a rectangle aside.  The solution is mainly based on the use of `(current bounding box)`.

**Remark.**
The alignment of the node with respect to the text is based on @Marco Daniel 's answer at
[How to make a tikz node, top-aligned with the rest of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39597/how-to-make-a-tikz-node-top-aligned-with-the-rest-of-the-text).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ibox}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={%
      ([yshift={-\ht\strutbox +.2ex}]current bounding box.north)
    },
    outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]
    \path (0, 0)
    node[anchor=north west,
    inner sep=0, outer sep=0,
    text width=\linewidth] (tmp)
    {#1};
    \draw (\linewidth +3ex, 0) rectangle
    ($(current bounding box.south east) +(\marginparwidth+5ex, 0)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{Verification}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \ibox{\lipsum[1]}
\item \ibox{\lipsum[2]}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.