# Invisible character equal to the height of capital letters

Tags: spacing, xetex, strut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create an invisible character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character)

How can I insert an invisible character (similar to `\strut`) which has a width of zero (won't impact word or letter spacing) and has a height equal to the height of an uppercase letter in currently selected font?

Comment: Also related: [Determine height and depth of letters relative to the font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22225/2552)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom{<some uppercase letter>}` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
\fbox{aaaa}\fbox{aaAa}\fbox{aaaa}
\fbox{aaaa}\fbox{aaAa}\fbox{aaaa\vphantom{A}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does TeX have no way of knowing the general height of all of the uppercase letters? E.g. a built-in measurement?

Comment: @Village: No, that size is not directly available. See [Determine height and depth of letters relative to the font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22227/2552) for more information on this.

Comment: You could construct this as a simple macro for easy reuse. You'd have to put all the capital letters into the `\vphantom`, but only once. Perhaps there's even a way of simplifying that down.

Comment: @Village: You could use `\vphantom{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ}` to ensure that take the maximum height of any uppercase character. The height is about 1.6ex, so `\vrule height 1.6ex depth 0pt width 0pt` would also work. See also [Definition of \strut explained](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21832/definition-of-strut-explained)