# align nodes horizontally in forest

Tags: forest

I am trying to build a horizontal tree using package forest, though I don't manage to get the nodes well aligned.
Here is an example and MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        calign=center,
        grow'=east, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        rounded corners, draw,
        }
        [A [B [C [D [E[F]]] [D' [E' [F']]] ]]]
    \end{forest}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        calign=center,
        grow'=east, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        rounded corners, draw, 
        }
        [g [B [g [D [E[F]]] [D' [E' [F']]] ]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

What I would like to get is something like in the first tree, while as you can see from the second one, the text in the nodes influences their alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `text height` and `text depth` explicitly such that all nodes have the same height and baseline no matter what the letter looks like.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        calign=center,
        grow'=east, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        rounded corners, draw,
        text height=1.4ex, text depth=0.2ex % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        [g [B [g [D [E[F]]] [D' [E' [F']]] ]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you get the values (1.4ex and 0.2ex) from?

Comment: Trial and error. It very much depends on which signs actually may occur. If you use parentheses, it has to be increased. Using larger values from the outset without needing them will result in nodes that look too big, or in letters off-center. So maybe you have to choose different values for subtrees where the letters are more uniform.

Comment: I expected some standard measures or constants, something like (an imaginary) `\maxfontheight`. I tried to google for it but found nothing

Comment: @g.tataranni See [Determine height and depth of letters relative to the font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22225/determine-height-and-depth-of-letters-relative-to-the-font-size)

Comment: @gtatr Alternatively, you could set a fixed height for your font by useing `\setlength{\ttlhght}{\totalheightof{characters in your tree}}`. I used this length to place a zero-width parbox (`\newcommand{\hghtbx}{\parbox[c][\ttlhght]{0pt}{}}`) in every node.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `\strut` to the nodes' contents automatically and reduce the `inner ysep` a bit so the nodes do not become too tall. You may still want some fine-tuning, but the default result may be better than it might be otherwise.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    calign=center,
    grow'=east, % tree direction
    parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, % edge anchors
    rounded corners, draw,
    inner ysep=1pt
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      content/.wrap value={\strut #1},
    }
  }
  [g [B [g [D [E[F]]] [D' [E' [F']]] ]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: with auto-<code>\strut</code>]