# Typesetting a minimalistic tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

How might I produce this

[image: tree]

in LaTeX, with or witohut TikZ?  I would like it if the lines could be
made to look exactly as in the picture.  Could it be done using the
en-rule (em-rule?) and the bar of the current font?  The bar should
descend from the middle of parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with forest. Please understand that I am not in the mood to type up all these items from your screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south,calign=fixed edge angles,
    grow=south,
    if={n==1}{child anchor=east}{child anchor=west},
    l sep=0.5em,
    s sep=1em,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south)  |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342056/121799
    for tree={
      content/.wrap value={\strut #1},
    }
  }
  }  
[science,anchor=center
 [experiment]
 [theory
  [duck]
  [koala]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* want to jam up the tree, here is a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south,calign=fixed edge angles,
    grow=south,
    inner ysep=0pt,
    if={n==1}{child anchor=east}{child anchor=west},
    l=0mm,
    l sep=1mm,
    s sep=0.5em,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south)  |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342056/121799
    for tree={
      content/.wrap value={\strut #1},
    }
  }
  }  
[science,anchor=center
 [experiment]
 [theory
  [duck]
  [koala]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Is it perhaps possible to fix the line lengths?

Comment: @Toothrot Yes, but what precisely does "fix" mean. Do you want them to become longer, shorter or equal?

Comment: Something more similar to the original, ie. shorter lines.  The
horizontal something like an en-rule and the vertical something like a
bar.  And the length of `experiment' should preferably not shorten the
line to the right of it.